# Как нарисовать прямоугольник без границ в C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder

Как нарисовать прямоугольник (и вообще фигуру) без этих границ в 1 пиксель. Вот вырезка из книги Ч. Петзолда "Программирование для Windows 95":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Не у всего можно убрать... Параметр BorderWidth, - например, у кнопки нет его, а у панельки есть. Если нужен именно прямоугольник, то на вкладке стандарт ищите "panel".

Comment: Я не об этом. Я рисую на Canvas-e элемента TImage (или TPaintBox).